# Vue.js: How to concatenate v-model value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to make this work:

```
<div v-for="index in 4">
  <input v-model="'invoice_' + index" >
</div>
```

just like this:

```
<div v-for="index in 4">
  <input v-model="invoice_1" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be better if you put all the *invoices_*s variables in a single object and then refer to them by key, something like follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    invoices: {
      invoice_1: '1',
      invoice_2: '2',
      invoice_3: '3',
      invoice_4: '4'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="index in 4">
    <input v-model="invoices['invoice_' + index]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not able to change how your data is structured, [you can access the data object via `$data`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data). So you could bind to your invoice properties via `$data['invoice_' + index]`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      invoice_1: 'a',
      invoice_2: 'b',
      invoice_3: 'c',
      invoice_4: 'd'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="index in 4">
    <input v-model="$data['invoice_' + index]" >
  </div>
</div>
```

---

However, I agree with Psidom that it would make more sense to change your data structure if you are able to. Although, I would make `invoices` an array and just access each invoice by the index. This way you don't need to explicitly name each invoice with an index:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      invoices: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="index in 4">
    <input v-model="invoices[index-1]">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Even better would be to make `invoices` an array of objects, each with its own `id` and `value`. This way you can render the entire array of `invoices` (via `v-for="invoice in invoices"`) without having to keep track of any indexes. This also allows you to provide a unique [`key` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) for each rendered element:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      invoices: [
        { id: 1, value: 'a' },
        { id: 2, value: 'b' },
        { id: 3, value: 'c' },
        { id: 4, value: 'd' }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="invoice in invoices" :key="invoice.id">
    <input v-model="invoice.value">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following code

Define 'invoices' as an empty object in the data state

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      invoices: {}
    }
  }
})
```

In the template, you can pass in the custom string with an index value

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="index in 4">
    <input v-model="invoices['invoice__' + index]">
  </div>
</div>
```

I used the above code to implement custom checkbox value of items.

At the end, the 'invoices' object will output as 'invoice__0: true', 'invoice__1:false' and so on.